# How to initialise NSMutableArray in swift AppDelegate and use it in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, swift

The Swift part

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var tableData:NSMutableArray = []
```

The Objective C part

```
NSMutableString *data = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
...
[appDelegate.tableData addObject:data];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.tableData);
```

I can see the data but appDelegate.tableData is empty and gives (null) in log console without crashing, just empty?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried debugger?

Comment: no just NSLog, I was hoping it would be something stupid from my part. Will try to add break point and see if it tells me something more because I have no clue.

Comment: added a picture from debugger

Comment: aaaaa thx now i get it :D `appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` was not called thanks

Comment: Can you add answer `appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` didn't get called so I can accept?